# gcc exit with undefined reference to function in header file

Tags: c, gcc, include, makefile

I want to compile a small program which has a pretty straight forward makefile, but I seem unable to get it working. Maybe you can help me. The makefile has the following targets:

```
visca-cli: visca-cli.c libvisca_hl.o
    gcc -Wall -o visca-cli visca-cli.c /usr/local/lib/libvisca.so libvisca_hl.o

libvisca_hl.o: libvisca_hl.c
    gcc -Wall -c libvisca_hl.c
```

I can 'make libvisca_hl.o' successfully and create the .o file. But 'make visca-cli' fails with error messages like

> libvisca_hl.c:(.text+0x468a): undefined reference to
>   `VISCA_get_md_disptime'

for every single function defined in libvisca.h (here it's VISCA_get_md_disptime)

Here are the include sections from the various files (ommitting standard libraries):

In visca-cli.c:

```
#include "libvisca.h"
#include "libvisca_hl.h"
```

In libvisca_hl.c:

```
#include "libvisca_hl.h"
```

In libvisca_hl.h:

```
#include "libvisca.h"
```

All includes quoted with "" are present in the local directory where I run make and where all the sourcefiles are. There are no subfolders. So I guess the problem lies with the makefile? Any help appreciated!

Comment: Nah. Includes have nothing to do with linker errors. Libraries do. You are not linking against a required library which contains the **definition** (as opposed to the **declaration**) of the function in question.

Comment: OP *is* linking to the library which contains the definition.  He/she is just doing it in the wrong place on the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of libraries and objects on your compilation/link command line matters.  In your case, you just need to put the shared object at the end:

```
gcc -Wall -o visca-cli visca-cli.c libvisca_hl.o /usr/local/lib/libvisca.so
```

On most systems `/usr/local/lib` is already part of the standard library search path, so you could simplify further:

```
gcc -Wall -o visca-cli visca-cli.c libvisca_hl.o -lvisca
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much. I've been sitting the whole day trying to make this work.